# How to overwirte Django Backend?

Tags: django, single-sign-on

I would like to give access to the backend of a Django project for all my users who is registered in a specified Azure AD group.

I use django_microsoft_auth package to handle SSO Usage — [django-microsoft-auth](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

When I log for the 1st time with an account from Azure AD, the account is created in Django.
But I would like to :

- change the loggin (by default is using the email address as loggin),
- force is_staff = True
- and add the user to a django group.

I think I must overwrite the authenticate method from BaseBackend. I did follow the doc [DjangoProject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) but I having trouble to make it work

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('microsoft/', include('microsoft_auth.urls', namespace='microsoft')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = […,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'microsoft_auth,
    'django.contrib.sites'
    …]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["microsoft_auth.backends.MicrosoftAuthenticationBackend","django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend","myproject.signals.SettingsBackend"]

ADMIN_LOGIN = env(“my_login”)
ADMIN_PASSWORD = env(“my_password_h”)
```

In signals.py (located in the same directory of settings.py)
I used the code from the django doc and I try to add a groupe to the user.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission


class SettingsBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        login_valid = settings.ADMIN_LOGIN == username
        pwd_valid = check_password(password, settings.ADMIN_PASSWORD)
        if login_valid and pwd_valid:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                # Create a new user. There's no need to set a password
                # because only the password from settings.py is checked.
                user = User(username=username)
                user.is_staff = True
                user.is_superuser = True
                group = Group.objects.get(name="myGroupDjango")
                user.groups.add(group)
                user.save()                
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

My custom authenticate method doesn’t seem to work.

What did I miss ?